# Using Java's PathIterator within MATLAB

Tags: matlab, java

I'm looking to use PathIterator on an area within MATLAB in order to store the vertices in an array, and the returned int seems to be correct, but I cannot seem to get the coordinates to return correctly ([the field coords in the online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html)).

In the command line for testing purposes:

```
myArea = 
java.awt.geom.Area@c506df7

AT = java.awt.geom.AffineTransform();

PI = myArea.getPathIterator(AT)
PI =
java.awt.geom.AreaIterator@56118528

coords = zeros(1,6);

PI.currentSegment(coords)
ans =
0

PI.next()
PI.currentSegment(coords)
ans = 
1
```

And according to the documentation, the vertices should be stored in the coords array, but the array isn't changing.

I've tried declaring a coords as a java array within MATLAB, but then currentSegment(coords) will not run at all.  Could this be a problem with myArea being an area rather than a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You came across one of the most annoying limitations of Matlab-Java interaction. Matlab [automatically converts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/mps_java/data-conversion-with-java-and-matlab-types.html) java primitives and arrays, such as `double`/`float` to and from Matlab numerical types. This allows you to pass a `float[]` array to java method (but not an empty array, which will be passed as `null` instead!), but it would do so by passing a reference to the *copy* it creates. So even though java method modifies this copy by reference, your original array in Matlab is never changed.

So unfortunately, it is not possible to use such java method as is. Your only option is to write a custom java wrapper method around it. You would either need to return the array explicitly, or else expose `Float[]` to Matlab (i.e. non-primitive, which would not be converted by Matlab in any way) instead of `float[]`, converting back and forth inside the wrapper. Which way to choose is mostly a matter of personal preference.